# form submit with enter key pressed or click submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I have a form that I want the user the be able to use the

Enter key or Click on the button to submit it.

Here is the code I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Blah</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetSrc()
{
document.getElementById("myIfreme1").src = 'http://' +   
document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Enter URL:  http://
<input type="text" id="txtSRC" />
<input type="button" value="GO" onclick="SetSrc()" />
</form>
<div style="clear:both">320 width</div>
<iframe id="myIfreme1" src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" height="480" width="320" 
scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you not google HTML form submission

Comment: Might I suggest putting some more information about what doesn't work. For example in this case I imagine that you don't have a button to click at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your form needs a submit button... so add `<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>` inside your form.

You should check out [these articles on HTML Forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms)...

Comment: thanks, but that does not activate the form "SetSrc()" on pressing enter key

Comment: @jhoyla If you look at the code, the <input type="button" value="GO" onclick="SetSrc()" /> is the button. I tried switching that to button and it does not work.

Comment: @user2518599 then add `onclick="SetSrc()" ` to the submit button.

Comment: I switched the input to this: <button type="button" value="GO" onclick="SetSrc()">Hello Button</button> it works the same, press the Enter Key and nothing.

Comment: @user2518599 type="submit"